# Is KnockoutJS SEO friendly

Tags: javascript, seo, knockout.js

My question is simple: is KnockoutJS SEO friendly? I'm having a website and using Knockout data template intensively, but I'm doubting if Google crawler would ever find out about my site, as the page is a large bunch of template, no real HTML markup is present.And how can I improve this? Using RSS?

Comment: A similar [question][1] has already been asked on stackexchange.programmers.com.


  [1]: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144165/is-dynamic-html-layout-good-from-an-seo-perspective

Comment: No. All that data coming via JS isn't going to the bot. Here's some  related discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/Bg-okN1xc3Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this article:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-1-introducing-pushstate/

In short, with html5 pushstate, you can easily take advantage of both worlds:
1. the speed of ajax
2. the ability to display page content normally for clients with no js support (including search engines)

Comment: It does not answer the real question... What about the dynamically generated content ? Google bot come and find only templates without data, how to resolve that ?

Comment: @G.Ghez Google bots are capable of rendering and understanding web pages like modern browsers do, [see the article at Google Webmasters blog](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)

Answer (score -1):

KnockoutJS, a client-side JavaScript framework, can pose SEO challenges as search engines prioritize content in initial HTML markup. To enhance SEO, consider server-side rendering (SSR) for pre-rendered content, ensuring functionality without JavaScript, using structured data markup, creating XML sitemaps, and updating content regularly. While RSS feeds offer content updates, they won't directly resolve dynamic content indexing. Prioritize SSR and SEO best practices for optimal results.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34895696)